# Permutation for numbers in C

Tags: c, algorithm, permutation, combinatorics, factorial

I'm trying to write a C function to list all permutations of a set of numbers, in groups of five, including repeat numbers:

```
15-11-49-43-5
2-30-34-6-11
```

So it's easy enough to write a function to grab all permutations of a number set and throw them out, but mapped to a certain group size, i'm somewhat stuck..

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean  "mapped to a certain group size"?

Comment: @Niki Yoshiuchi: i think he means hardcoded loops

Comment: I rather meant, if i had to find all the permutations of 1 to 49 that are in groups of 5.

Comment: As in, i've got 1 to 49 and i want to print all the combinations of all the numbers in groups of five, repetition allowed. Tl;Dr all possible combinations of numbers 1 - 49 in groups of five (see example)

Comment: I think http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system has information you can use.

Answer (score 1):

```
void visit(int *Value, int N, int k)
{
  static level = -1;
  level = level+1; Value[k] = level;

  if (level == N)
    print(Value, N);
  else
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
      if (Value[i] == 0)
        visit(Value, N, i);

  level = level-1; Value[k] = 0;
}
```

For more information you can visit http://www.bearcave.com/random_hacks/permute.html

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to get a specific permutation, like eg

- permutation 1 == 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
- permutation 2 == 1, 1, 1, 1, 2
- permutation 49 == 1, 1, 1, 1, 49
- permutation 50 == 1, 1, 1, 2, 1
- permutation 42000000 == 8, 14, 49, 35, 42

Convert the number you want (minus 1) to base 49 and use the "digits" (plus 1) for the result.

```
42000000 - 1 = 41999999
41999999 = (7 * 49^4) + (13 * 49^3) + (48 * 49^2) + (34 * 49) + 41
result      8            14            49            35         42
```

Answer (score 0):

I would split this up into two problems: a) find all the combinations nCk of your array of size n b) find all the permutations of an array of length k.  You said you already know how to do the permutations, so let's focus on the combinations:

```
void combinations(int *arr, int *comb, int n, int k, int kCurr)
{
    if(kCurr >= k)
    {
        permutations(comb, k);
        return;
    }
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        comb[kCurr] = arr[i];
        combinations(arr+i, comb, n-i, k, kCurr+1);
    }
}
```

which would be called like this:

```
int myArray[49] = {1, 2, ..., 49};
int myCombs[5];
combinations(myArray, myCombs, 49, 5, 0);
```

This computes all the combinations 49C5 by building up the array `myCombs`, and when it is full it calls a function `permutations`.  If `permutations` is implemented properly then you will print out all permutations of all combinations of 49C5.

EDIT: Duh, you can just do `combinations(arr, comb, n, k kCurr+1)` as the recursive step, and then just print the array in the base case (or do whatever).

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to find all permutations but not all combinations of size 5, then just find all permutations of:

int A[49] = { 0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };

Each permutation of array A corresponds to a combination containing number (i+1), if and only if A[i] == 1, for each i in [0, 49).

Answer (score 0):

Since repetition is allowed, and the output set is smaller than the input set, it's not actually a permutation that you're after at all.

You're just looking for a simple count:

```
for (a[0] = 1; a[0] <= 49; a[0]++)
  for (a[1] = 1; a[1] <= 49; a[1]++)
    for (a[2] = 1; a[2] <= 49; a[2]++)
      for (a[3] = 1; a[3] <= 49; a[3]++)
        for (a[4] = 1; a[4] <= 49; a[4]++)
          printf("%d-%d-%d-%d-%d\n", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]);
```