# get the i-th combination of arrays of numbers

Tags: c, algorithm, permutation, combinations

I know there are many similar questions, and I have read them for hours. But none of them seems to meet my requirement.

**My problem:**

given n int arrays, and each of them has the form

```
array_i[] = {0, 1,...,count_i-1}, i = 0,1,...,n-1.
```

We choose one number of each array to make a combination, and the number of such combinations is

```
count_0*count_1*...*count_{n-1}
```

**For example**

```
array_0 = {0,1}
array_1 = {0,1,2}
array_2 = {0,1}
```

the 2*3*2 = 12 combinations are

```
 0| 0 0 0
 1| 0 0 1
 2| 0 1 0
 3| 0 1 1
 4| 0 2 0
 5| 0 2 1
 6| 1 0 0 
 7| 1 0 1
 8| 1 1 0
 9| 1 1 1
10| 1 2 0
11| 1 2 1
```

I want to get the i-th combination (e.g. the 9-th combination is `{1,1,1}`) and get it efficiently. I've tried the idea of base-n conversion, something like this [Permutation for numbers in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765215/permutation-for-numbers-in-c/3767756#3767756). But it's not efficient since the base has to be the largest `count_i`, which might be unnecessary. I've also thought about the idea of using different bases for each bit, but it's tricky to get the relation right.

Any suggestions are truly welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference from your link ([Permutation for numbers in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765215/permutation-for-numbers-in-c/3767756#3767756)) is that 49^i becomes a product of count_j's:

```
index_0 = ( i / sub_0 ) % count_0
index_1 = ( i / sub_1 ) % count_1
...
```

where you precomputed

```
sub_0 = count_1*count_2*...*count_{n-1}
sub_1 = count_2*count_3*...*count_{n-1}
...
```

In your example with counts = 2,3,2, we have sub=6,2,1, hence for i=9 index=1,1,1

Comment: but applying your method to my example, prod_0 = 2, prod_1 = 1, and the indices for the 9-th combination are index_0 = 9%2 = 1, 9%1 = 0?

Comment: Redefine your arrays to run from 0 to count-1; otherwise your expression for the total number of combinations is wrong. Then count_i becomes the number of elements in array_i. Then in your example counts are 2,3,2.

Comment: Yes you are right. But now prod_0 = 6, prod_1 = 2, and the indices for the 9-th combination are index_0 = 9%6 = 3, 9%2 = 1?

Comment: Thank you. It's really neat.